# Pytorch accumulates tensors from the previous batch(es)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have been trying to implement a trasnformer-UNet hybrid model for image segmentation. Whenever I try to train the model, it keeps running out of memory. Initially, I thought this was due to the size of the model and tried to decrease parameters like batch size, number of attention heads, number of transformer layers etc.

All these steps only delayed the inevitable, running out of memory. I even tried to use cloud GPUs, but still no luck. Here's a screenshot of pytorch's memory snapshot tool:

[image]

(I do empty the cache by calling `torch.cuda.empty_cache`)

I suspect that the some tensors are being retained because I use a list to implement the skip connection (the necessary tensors are appended to the list).

```
class convolutionalEncoder(torch.nn.Module):
    
    class conv_block(torch.nn.Module):
 
        def __init__(self, out_channels, device) -> None:
            super().__init__()
            self.conv = LazyConv2d(out_channels= out_channels, kernel_size= 2,
                                   stride= (2, 2), padding= 'valid', device= device)
            
 
        def forward(self, X):
            global relu
 
            X = self.conv(X)
            X = relu(X)
 
            return X
 
    def __init__(self, device) -> None:
        super(convolutionalEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv_block_list = []
        self.skip_conn = []
        for i in range(num_skip_conn):
            self.conv_block_list.append(self.conv_block(filters[i], device))
 
    def forward(self, X):
 
        for i in range(num_skip_conn):
            X = self.conv_block_list[i](X)
            self.skip_conn.append(X)
 
        return self.skip_conn
```

[Here's a link to the code](https://pastebin.com/xJeVjUNC)

[Here's a link to the pickle file (memory snapshot dump)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13EZ29fyZsNk7Kthe2j7t1ztVWKDtU_K2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use https://pytorch.org/memory_viz to view the memory snapshot dump.

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*, *not* in an external repo; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is building a list of every skip connection that isn't reset between batches

```py
class convolutionalEncoder(torch.nn.Module):
    
    class conv_block(torch.nn.Module):
 
        ...
 
    def __init__(self, device) -> None:
        super(convolutionalEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv_block_list = []
        self.skip_conn = []
        for i in range(num_skip_conn):
            self.conv_block_list.append(self.conv_block(filters[i], device))
 
    def forward(self, X):
 
        for i in range(num_skip_conn):
            X = self.conv_block_list[i](X)
            self.skip_conn.append(X)
 
        return self.skip_conn
```

`self.skip_conn` should just be a normal list, not an attribute that is retained between batches. What is happening is the tensors for every single batch are added to `self.skip_conn`, essentially storing the entire dataset in that list until you oom.

Just replace it with a new normal list every time

```py
    def forward(self, X):
 
        skip_conn = []
        for i in range(num_skip_conn):
            X = self.conv_block_list[i](X)
           skip_conn.append(X)
 
        return skip_conn
```

Comment: That fixed it! Any idea why this happens? Should an object (and it's attributes, in essence) be destroyed once it goes out of scope?

Comment: When you create the list via `self.skip_conn = []`, the list is part of the model object itself. So the tensors added to the list are held in memory as long as the model object exists. Your code also never reset the list, so your code stored all tensors persistently inside the model until oom